# Is it possible to use a GitHub repository directly in DevOps for CI

Tags: github, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I don't want to import a repo but use github repo directly.

I was disappointed that you can only link to your GitHub repo for Project Management boards. I want to link to Github for Continuous Integration in the Build pipeline..but DevOps is forcing me to Import the repo so it becomes a new repo local to DevOps separate to the one on Github.....Is there a way around this such that you can do continuous integration with your GitHub repo on DevOps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,you can use a GitHub repository directly in DevOps for CI.To achieve this, you only need to select Github as source when create a new build pipeline:

[image]

Then you can enable continuous integration in Triggers of pipeline.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I love it when you go to bed with a really annoying problem and you wake up to find someone has solved it.

Comment: FYI: I initially made the bad assumption you had to setup a Repo in devops before you could do a continuous build - so i imported my GitHub Repo to devops - no link option.

Comment: Using Github for build feedback: Creating a build from github worked just fine. However when I went to create a release pipeline from it - I ran into trouble with the Service Plan - I couldn't select my existing Visual Studio one. Not sure what was going on, but in the end I went into Service Connections and selected the 2 plans that I had and made the "GitHub" user an Administrator. This then allowed me to configure my Release pipeline and add a Web App